# Conversion of VARCHAR to DATETIME

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have a `VARCHAR` that holds `datetime` data in the following format:

```
15/04/2014 16:05
```

I need to convert this to `datetime` (with the exact format as before) but get an out of range error on the conversion:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, @endDate, 108)
```

The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Could any advise the best way to successfully convert? Bear in mind i cannot change the source format and eventually need to compare the date to see if it is past the present day.

Comment: If instead of the 15th day, what if it were the 8th day?  Would it be `08/04/2014 16:05`, or would it be `8/04/2014 16:05`?  This is important for an answer I can provide

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to use 103 instead of 108 for the final parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Please use date constant values that are language/country independent

```
-- Independent constant (natural date)
DECLARE @END_DTE VARCHAR(20) = '20140415 16:05'

-- Show the result
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @END_DTE, 108) AS FORMAT_DTE
```